# C# - Can't send mail in WIndows Azure via Gmail SMTP

Tags: azure, smtpclient

This is my Web.config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network defaultCredentials="true" enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" userName="xxxxxxx@gmail.com" password="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

My method:

```
public static void EmailVerification(string email, string nickname)
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(email);

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

        message.Subject = "Test";
        message.Body = "Test";
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch(SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

My failure SmtpException:

```
Failure sending mail.
```

InnerException:

```
Unable to connect to the remote server
```

I'm testing it locally but I guess it should work. I have to run it on Windows Azure, I tried and it didn't work too. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail/32336#32336

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic authentication and default network credentials options are mutually exclusive; if you set defaultCredentials to true and specify a user name and password, the default network credential is used, and the basic authentication data is ignored.

Use

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" userName="xxxxxxx@gmail.com" password="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: I see, I used like this: <network enableSsl="true" defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com" password="xxxxxxxxxx"/> I needed to change the port to 587