# Cannot use Gmail smtp from Azure Cloud Service

Tags: .net, azure, smtp, gmail

My code for sending email through Gmail's smtp:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("my_user_name", "my_password");

MailMessage message =
     new MailMessage(new MailAddress("from...@gmail.com"), new MailAddress("to...@gmail.com"));
message.Body = "body";
message.Subject = "subject";
client.Send(message);
```

The code works on my local machine and when I publish at Azure as "Web Site".

BUT when I publish in a **"Cloud Service"** I get this exception:

```
 System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection
 or the client was not authenticated. The server response was:
 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
```

Is there anything that differ a Windows Azure "Web site" from a "Cloud Service" that could have this effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use following SMTP settings in Web.config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="xxxxxxx@gmail.com" password="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I think you are passing wrong credentials. Use @gmail.com suffix in your user name and try to set bodyhtml property true also...

Hope this will work for you.. It always work correctly to me..

Check answer's comment in the [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559431/c-sharp-cant-send-mail-in-windows-azure-via-gmail-smtp).

Comment: Bingo! Suffixing user name with @gmail.com did the trick on the "Cloud Service" app.

Comment: actually gmail take complete email id as user name either you configure it in outlook or any client.

Comment: yes maybe, but it worked without the @gmail.com in cassini and in Azure as a "Web Site". Maybe I was just lucky there :)

Answer (score 14):

I experienced this exact problem. However, I experienced the problem regardless of the fact that I was using the `<system.net>` configuration settings and I was using the proper credentials, host, port, etc.

The problem was that Google was rejecting the authentication request that was coming from Azure. I found this out by logging into the Gmail account that I was using for the SMTP Client in my code. Once I logged into the Gmail account, I noticed a red-bar-header-warning that said

> Someone signed in from a location that isn't typical for your account.
>   If it wasn't you, change your password immediately.

in addition to the warning, I received an email that said:

> Someone recently tried to use an application to sign in to your Google
>   Account, xxxxx@gmail.com. We prevented the sign-in attempt in case
>   this was a hijacker trying to access your account. Please review the
>   details of the sign-in attempt:
>
> - Monday, August 27, 2012 10:33:59 PM GMT
> - IP Address: 168.62.48.183
> - Location: United States
>
> If you do not recognize this sign-in attempt, someone else might be
>   trying to access your account. You should sign in to your account and
>   reset your password immediately. Find out how at
>   http://support.google.com/accounts?p=reset_pw
>
> If this was you, and you want to give this application access to your
>   account, complete the troubleshooting steps listed at
>   http://support.google.com/mail?p=client_login
>
> Sincerely, The Google Accounts Team

After I followed the steps listed in the provided link, my Azure Website was able to successfully log into my Gmail account and use Gmail as the SMTP Client.

Comment: FYI - You need to log into the gmail account that being used from your code.  I received the 'suspicious activity' email to a linked account, and wasn't able to authorize the IP address.

Comment: You legend! I had to log in with my gmail account again, flag the suspicous sign-ins as legit and go to http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha. That sorted it out.

Comment: you are a life saver THANK YOU! i've been pulling my hair out on this one for a couple hours now. eeesh!

Answer (score 8):

As instructed on the Google troubleshooting page, going to the following link and logging in from my local computer fixed the error when sending email from an Azure website for me.

http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Answer (score 4):

It seems your connection is rejected by the SMTP server either because it is not SSL enabled or the credentials are incorrect. You would need to setup SSL and network credentials in your web.config as below:

```
<system.net>
 <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" userName="xxxxxxx@gmail.com" password="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

More info is available in this SO discussion: 
[C# - Can't send mail in WIndows Azure via Gmail SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559431/c-sharp-cant-send-mail-in-windows-azure-via-gmail-smtp)

Answer (score 0):

Like said before your username should contain "**@googlemail.com**". In my code (java) I'm using **port 465** to sent mails through google mail.

Answer (score 0):

**Create an "App Password" in Gmail Account**

Go to your [Gmail account](https://myaccount.google.com/)

In the **Security** section

1.- Go to **Google Access**

2.- Allow **Two-step verification**

3.- Create a new **App password**

4.- Use that password instead normal in your Web.config or source code